# How does the 'label' keyword work in MASM?

Tags: assembly, keyword, masm

What does this assembler code do?

```
someName label word
         dw 8 dup(0)
```

How does `label` work?

Comment: `label` is not a CPU instruction, it's a feature of your assembler. Which assembler are you using, and for which system?

Comment: This is not my own program, I just need to figure this out. So all I can say is that the program is for Intel 386+ processors. And the code snippet is written in data segment

Comment: But with what assembler?  I assume MASM or TASM, from the `8 dup(0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically `label` creates a symbolic name for the code/data that follows and also assigns it a type. It's similar to defining a variable with given name and type/size. But it does not actually allocate space for it. It can be used to create aliases to variables.

Comment: So if I got it right I can access the first word of the following memory by someName?

Answer (score 2):

Despite your lack of details about which assembler you are using, I can take a guess.

The `someName label word` statement assigns the current address (of type `word`) to `someName`. This means that later in the program, you can use the label `someName` instead of a specific address.

The `dw` statement reserves some amount of space of type `word`. I'm not entirely certain what the `8dup(0)` means, but it might be 8 words (16 bytes) of space.

Comment: dw 8dup(0) means allocating memory of 8 words and writing in each word the value 0

Answer (score 1):

A label can be placed at the beginning of a statement. During assembly, the label is assigned the current value of the active location counter and serves as an instruction operand. There are two types of lables: symbolic and numeric.

Answer (score 0):

A label is just a name for a specific location in your code or a specific memory address. By using labels instead of actual addresses, your code can be maintained much more easy because the labels do not need to change when you add code and move around code. The compiler compiles it to actual addresses underneath.